# php pdo where request does not function for the giving value?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm new in php and ajax and i want that once the user select a name, I get the rows that have this name value from the BDD. I have used used Jquery post for that :

Here is my BDD request:

```
public static function getIdPre($nomp) //My problem is on this $nomp var
{
  require_once('database.php');
  $db = DbConnection::get();
  $prestQuer = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM prst WHERE nomp=? ');
  $prestQuer->execute(array($nomp));
  $row= $prestQuer->fetch();
  return($row['idp']);
}
```

Here is where I get the value of **$nomp** :

```
 if((isset($_POST['nompr']))){
       $nomp=$_POST['nompr'];
      $FilterTarifs=MainController::getPrstFilterTarif($nomp);
      foreach ($FilterTarifs as $FilterTarif) {
    ...}
```

Once I do something like this :

```
$FilterTarifs=MainController::getPrstFilterTarif('Octroi'); It works perfectly but once I let it in the first way :

$FilterTarifs=MainController::getPrstFilterTarif($nomp);
```

it does not work even though the value is correctly got it from Jquery post :

```
    $("#filtrBtn").click(function () {
     if(nompres===undefined)
     {
       alert("Choisir un filtre d'abord ");
     }
     else
     {
       $(".bnqInfos").html("");
       $.post(basUrl+'views/component/filterdata.php',
         {
           nompr:nompres,//Here is the given name
         }, function(data) {
          // alert(data);
            $(".bnqInfos").html(data);
        });
     }
  });
```

Here is my controller function getIdPre():

```
  public static function getPrstFilterTarif($nomp)
    {
      $idpr=Prest::getIdPre($nomp);
      $result=Tarif::getTarifFilter($idpr);
      return $result;
    }
```

I have not understood Why it doesnt function.
What should I do? Can someone help please.

Comment: Show how you're calling `getIdPre()`.

Comment: here is it :   public static function getPrstFilterTarif($nomp)
    {
      $idpr=Prest::getIdPre($nomp);
      $result=Tarif::getTarifFilter($idpr);
      return $result;
    }

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: If you put `var_dump($nomp);` in `getIdPre()`, does it show the correct value?

Comment: do you mean to do something like this :$idpr=Prest::getIdPre(var_dump($nomp)); the result is :C:\wamp\www\Mini_Prj\controllers\mainController.php:25:string ' Octroi' (length=7)

Comment: My God Bless you Barmar you helped me to get the solution.

Comment: I meant put `var_dump($nomp);` as the first line in `getIdPre`. But it looks like the problem is that `$nomp` has an extra space at the beginning. Use `trim()` to remove surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `$nomp` doesn't have extra whitespace around it.

```
$nomp = trim($_POST['nomp']);
```

Comment: My God blesss you you have saved my life. I have found the solution and I have post it.Thank you very very much.